# Different model output in Mac and PC

Tags: r, macos, lme4, multi-level

I have been working on my PC to analyse my multilevel data. I am now working on a Mac and have run the same model. Some of the output is the same but some is quite different. I can't seem to work out why. Here is the model:

```
> loss.2 <- glmer.nb(Loss_across.Chain ~ Posn.c*Valence.c + (Valence.c|mood.c/Chain), data = FinalData_forpoisson, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", check.conv.grad = .makeCC("warning", 0.05)))
```

On the PC I got this output:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: Negative Binomial(4.9852)  ( log )
Formula: Loss_across.Chain ~ Posn.c * Valence.c + (Valence.c | mood.c/Chain)
   Data: FinalData_forpoisson
Control: ..3

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  1894.7   1945.3   -936.4   1872.7      725 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.3882 -0.7225 -0.5190  0.4375  7.1873 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name        Variance  Std.Dev.  Corr
 Chain:mood.c (Intercept) 8.782e-15 9.371e-08     
              Valence.c   9.608e-15 9.802e-08 0.48
 mood.c       (Intercept) 0.000e+00 0.000e+00     
              Valence.c   1.654e-14 1.286e-07  NaN
Number of obs: 736, groups:  Chain:mood.c, 92; mood.c, 2

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      -0.19255    0.04794  -4.016 5.92e-05 ***
Posn.c           -0.61011    0.04122 -14.800  < 2e-16 ***
Valence.c        -0.27372    0.09589  -2.855  0.00431 ** 
Posn.c:Valence.c  0.38043    0.08245   4.614 3.95e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Posn.c Vlnc.c
Posn.c       0.491              
Valence.c    0.029 -0.090       
Psn.c:Vlnc. -0.090  0.062  0.491
```

On the Mac I got this output:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: Negative Binomial(4.9852)  ( log )
Formula: Loss_across.Chain ~ Posn.c * Valence.c + (Valence.c | mood.c/Chain)
   Data: FinalData_forpoisson
Control: ..3

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  1894.7   1945.3   -936.4   1872.7      725 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.3882 -0.7225 -0.5190  0.4375  7.1873 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name        Variance  Std.Dev.  Corr
 Chain:mood.c (Intercept) 1.242e-13 3.524e-07     
              Valence.c   4.724e-13 6.873e-07 0.98
 mood.c       (Intercept) 7.998e-16 2.828e-08     
              Valence.c   3.217e-14 1.793e-07 1.00
Number of obs: 736, groups:  Chain:mood.c, 92; mood.c, 2

Fixed effects:
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)       2.947e-05  4.794e-02   0.001    1.000
Posn.c            7.441e-05  4.122e-02   0.002    0.999
Valence.c        -4.011e-05  9.589e-02   0.000    1.000
Posn.c:Valence.c -6.672e-05  8.245e-02  -0.001    0.999

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Posn.c Vlnc.c
Posn.c       0.491              
Valence.c    0.029 -0.090       
Psn.c:Vlnc. -0.090  0.062  0.491
```

Does anyone know why the output might be different across the two platforms and how I might be able to get them to align?

Comment: Have you compared the default options on both platforms?  I would imagine that they are different.  For example, one may be removing NAs and the other may leave them.  You can check using options().

Comment: the Mac output is probably wrong.  Discussed in detail at https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/319 .  NB models are, unfortunately, still fragile.  Could you try observation-level random effects in a Poisson model instead and, if the results are sufficiently similar, live with them instead?  Or use glmmADMB or glmmTMB ... ??

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174532/different-model-output-in-mac-and-pc

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker. Unfortunately I haven't had any success in getting models to run in glmmADMB. I get a series of error messages and haven't been able to resolve them. I think I may analse this data using a logistic binomial model instead as it's possible for me to code each 'item' that makes up the count as 'present' or 'absent'.